# Publishing ClickOnce application using NAnt and MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, nant

I'm attempting to publish a ClickOnce application using an MSBuild task within a NAnt script.  The certificate is installed on the machine and I believe it's finding it, as it's now getting past an earlier problem of it not being able to get the certificate itself.  However, it's now failing with the error:

> [msbuild]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4512,5):
>   error MSB4044: The "SignFile" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "CertificateThumbprint"

The task currently is called like this:

```
<msbuild  project="${SourceURL}/pathToProject/project.csproj" verbosity="Minimal">
  <property name="Configuration" value="Client" />
  <property name="Platform" value="AnyCPU" />
  <arg value="/p:ApplicationVersion=${actualVersion}" />
  <arg value="/p:CertificateThumbprint=XXX" />
  <arg value="/p:ManifestCertificateThumbprint=XXX" />
  <arg value="/t:publish" />
</msbuild>
```

How should I be passing the CertificateThumbprint into the publish task?  I'm trying to avoid having to switch directly to using signtool or mage, since I'd like to keep it as close as possible to using Visual Studio directly as possible.